# Animated node with ID 2 already exists

Tags: react-native

[image]

package.json

```
 {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "homepage": "<My URL>",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d web-build",
    "predeploy": "expo build:web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.10",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "expo": "^37.0.11",
    "modal-react-native-web": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-dialogbox": "^0.6.10",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-skeleton-content": "^1.0.13",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.12.11",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Have you tried by installing the latest version `(1.9.0)`of `react-native-reanimated`?

Comment: Also, please upgrade your expo version to `38`. It can solve your problem. Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/alexZajac/react-native-skeleton-content-nonexpo/issues/15)

Comment: It works Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure : )

Comment: Still getting this error on "expo": "^38.0.0",
   and  "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure your package lock or yarn lock don't still include references to older versions of `react-native-reanimated`

for me `react-native-skeleton` was still referencing to an old reanimated version.

Comment: can u tell me how u removed the older version?

Comment: selact everything in your `package.lock` or `yarn.lock`, delete it all, then save. re-run `yarn` or `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still experiencing this problem, especially after installing `react-native-skeleton`, all you need to do is to run:

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated@1.9.0
```

Comment: I was using version 1.11.2 and getting the error. Was this bug reintroduced?

Comment: I am still getting the error on occasion with 1.9.0 I have error boundaries, but those don't catch non-rendering issues

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn upgrade react-native-reanimated
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For new people here, check your package-lock.json and look for the react-native-reanimated version listed in other package dependencies, check the one that matches all and check the one you have in package.json, uninstall the current one and install the one from package-lock.json file.
In my case in the lock file, the version that was in all the packages was 2.12.0 and in the package.json I had 2.14.0, so I had to install 2.12.0.

Comment: Another thing that came up after upgrading to Expo 48 to get to the android 33 API, were all these types of errors so I decided to look for what packages or libraries were using react-native-reanimated, searching from Visual Code I realized that there was a library called draftbit/ui that was being used by another one just for the "LinearGradient" basically a View with faded colors.
The most recommended thing is that in recent versions of expo if you have this kind of problems remove react-native-reanimated and the libraries that use it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have another package that has a dependency with react-native-reanimated with a specific version.
You need to update react-native-reanimated to that version.
Check this [comment](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1072#issuecomment-836803163) by [jakub-gonet](https://github.com/jakub-gonet) to [Animated node with ID 2 already exists #1072](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1072):

> This is most likely caused by two instances of reanimated running simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

check the package.lock file, it has two reanimated plugins, so delete the old version
and also delete the node_modules, then give yarn install or npm install and run the app

Answer (score 0):

Delete the react-native-reanimated fileby

yarn remove react-native-reanimated

This solved my problem